# CMake add_subdirectory and recompiling

Tags: cmake

I've just migrated a somewhat large project from Visual Studio solutions to CMake and I've noticed a weird behavior.  I have something like the following structure:

```
project/CMakeLists.txt
project/code/CMakeLists.txt

project/code/library-1/CMakeLists.txt
project/code/library-1/*.hpp
project/code/library-1/*.cpp
project/code/library-2/CMakeLists.txt
project/code/library-2/*.hpp
project/code/library-2/*.cpp
...
project/code/library-n/CMakeLists.txt
project/code/library-n/*.hpp
project/code/library-n/*.cpp

project/demo/CMakeLists.txt
project/demo/demo-1/CMakeLists.txt
project/demo/demo-1/*.hpp
project/demo/demo-1/*.cpp
project/demo/demo-2/CMakeLists.txt
project/demo/demo-2/*.hpp
project/demo/demo-2/*.cpp
...
project/demo/demo-n/CMakeLists.txt
project/demo/demo-n/*.hpp
project/demo/demo-n/*.cpp
```

1. The root `CMakeLists.txt` file configures the compilation flags, macro definitions, etc. and uses CMake's `add_subdirectory()` to include targets defined by the libraries and demo projects.
2. The `code` sub-folder contains a flat list of sub-folders with each containing source code for a static library (as well as its target defined in a `CMakeLists.txt` file).
3. The `demo` sub-folder contains a flat list of sub-folders.  Each contains source code for an executable and associated `CMakeLists.txt` file.
4. Each library is a standalone component and builds independently from all other libraries and demo projects.
5. Each demo program depends on one or more of the different libraries in the `code` sub-folder.

This setup is really nice.  If I want to change build options, I only need to modify the root `CMakeLists.txt` and everything re-compiles with the new settings.  If I modify any source code anywhere in the tree, the appropriate libraries, if any, are recompiled and all dependent demo programs are also re-built.

However, if I modify *any* `CMakeLists.txt` file anywhere in the tree, the entire tree of libraries and programs is re-compiled without respect of dependencies.  To give an idea of what I mean, here a few parts of the CMake build scripts.

---

**`project/demo/CMakeLists.txt`**

```
# Resolve libraries built in `code` sub-folder.
link_directories(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})

set(demo-projects
  demo-1
  demo-2
  ...
  demo-n
)
foreach(demo-project ${demo-projects})
  add_subdirectory(${demo-project})
endforeach()
```

---

**`project/demo/demo-n/CMakeLists.txt`**

```
# Find all source code in the same folder.
file(GLOB ${demo-project}_headers
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.hpp
)
file(GLOB ${demo-project}_sources
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
)

# Select libraries to link with.
set(${demo-project}_libraries
  library-1
  library-2
  library-5
)

# Build the demo program.
add_executable(${demo-project}
  ${${demo-project}_headers}
  ${${demo-project}_sources}
)
if(${demo-project}_libraries)
  target_link_libraries(${demo-project} ${${demo-project}_libraries})
endif()

# Manually register some dependencies on other targets.
if(${demo-project}_dependencies)
  add_dependencies(${demo-project} ${${demo-project}_dependencies})
endif()
```

---

If I happen to modify `project/demo/demo-n/CMakeLists.txt` to add an extra library, like this:

```
set(${demo-project}_libraries
  library-1
  library-2
  library-5
  library-6
)
```

Then the *entire* source code for all libraries and demo programs in the project is re-compiled.  Why is this so?  Is there a better way to structure my scripts in order to avoid this?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has encountered this issue before.  It seems very painful for any medium sized project and must be horrible for larger projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens that my problem was cause by a totally unrelated issue.  I applied [Bill Hoffman's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8593536/313063) and the modifying any "CMakeLists.txt" file in the project ended up modifying the `CXX_FLAGS` (C++ compiler flags) variable in all generated Makefiles.

I traced that back to my root "CMakeLists.txt" file, which had something like the following:

```
if(MSVC)
  # ...
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /WX /wd4355" // depends on cached value.
    CACHE STRING "Debug compiler flags" FORCE)
  # ...
endif()
```

I changed it to the following.

```
if(MSVC)
  # ...
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
    "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /WX /wd4355" // no longer depends on cached value.
    CACHE STRING "Debug compiler flags" FORCE)
  # ...
endif()
```

CMake no longer repeats the `/WX /wd4355` flags when updating the build scripts and my project no longer re-compiles from scratch at each modification!

Comment: You might want to check for wd4355 and wx in the flags, and add them in when they are not there.  A cache FORCE can be frustrating for a user.  Imagine if someone wants to add an extra flag to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG via cmake-gui.  The way you have the code, they will add the flags they want, hit configure, and the flags will go away....

Comment: @BillHoffman: Thanks, I'll look into that.  I'm still somewhat of a newbie with CMake and haven't got through all of your book yet!

Comment: @BillHoffman right, if he wants to always add those flags to whatever the user sets the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` to, he should not be doing a `CACHE...FORCE` but just a plain `set(NAME "${NAME} stufftoadd")`. [Message explaining this: Globally add compiler options for gcc](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-January/018985.html)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you want to do is figure out what changes.  You can use git to help you do that if you have it installed.

1. Run cmake on your project with an out of source build
2. cd to build directory
3. create a git repo out of the build tree
   git add .
   git commit -m "add build tree"
4. change the cmakefile that causes the rebuild
5. re-run cmake on the build tree
   cmake .
6. run git diff and see what changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this helped me find the answer.  This is not an answer, so I won't accept it, but I'll grant you the bounty for helping me out!

Answer (score 3):

It is true that if any CMakeLists.txt file changes (or any input to it, such as the "source" file of a configure_file call) then CMake will re-run at the top level of your build tree, and regenerate the solution files and project files that have changed.

However, it should only regenerate files that are different from the last time that it ran... so based on what you've shown in your question, I do not have a good explanation for why everything is rebuilding.

On the other hand, CMake does leave it up to Visual Studio to decide what to re-build when a "build solution" is triggered. We do not express any dependencies for VS, other than putting the sources and headers in the right projects, setting include directories properly, and trusting VS to analyze the includes and rebuild things properly when headers and source files change.

You do not show any include_directories calls. Do you make those in your top level CMakeLists.txt file such that all sub-directories have the same set of include values? If so, perhaps that's the thing that's triggering a rebuild of everything.

We certainly do our best to make CMake produce build systems that minimize rebuild times.

Is your project public? Can I see the full source code for it and try to reproduce the problem on my own machine?

Comment: I don't use visual studio, I use NMake (actually [JOM](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/03/27/speeding-up-visual-c-qt-builds/)).  Any Idea how it behaves specifically with respect to NMake?

Comment: When you say "it should only regenerate files that are different from the last time that it ran" are you refering to CMake and the "CMakeLists.txt" files or NMake and the Makefiles?

Comment: Yes, the include directories are all specified up-front.  If that doesn't change, why would it trigger a re-build?  No, the project is not public (yet), but I can probably write up a simple project that exhibits the behavior and post that on GitHub.

Comment: Well, with a Makefile based system, CMake does generate the dependencies that are expressed in the Makefiles. I would follow Bill Hoffman's advice as the next step to figure out what is changing when you re-run CMake. When I say "regenerate files that are different", I mean CMake does a copy-if-different operation on most generated files (make files, *and* VS sln and vcproj files...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the way CMake generates Visual Studio solution/project files, but I'm guessing it's generating one (set?) for your entire project. Due to the nature of the way CMake works (I can't find good documentation on this; maybe the "Mastering CMake" book?), if the subdirectory project files are not separate, it will regenerate them any time a CMakeLists.txt file is changed. Then, Visual Studio would be responsible for rebuilding the whole thing or not (I'm guessing that it rebuilds it when it sees that the project file has changed).

The [documentation for add_subdirectory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_subdirectory) does say

> The CMakeLists.txt file in the specified source directory will be processed immediately by CMake before processing in the current input file continues beyond this command.

That seems to indicate that all the subdirectories are processed as part of the main project.

That same documentation mentions the use of the `project` command in a subdirectory. It's talking about when you use the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` argument, but it seems possible (worth a try) that it could help in your situation anyway. For example, maybe if CMake generates the demo code as its own project, the main code won't get rebuilt when the demo project file changes.

I think that, to get a definitive answer, you may need to post on the [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/mailing.html) (and if you get a good answer, post it here).

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio anymore, I use NMake and [JOM](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/03/27/speeding-up-visual-c-qt-builds/) to compile.  I haven't tested for the same behavior with Visual Studio project files.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems your quote from the documentation might explain the behavior.  If the `CMakeLists.txt` are processed "immediately", it would indeed give the impression that CMake needs to regenerate the entire set of build scripts, resulting in build scripts that are newer than their targets, which then causes a re-build.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try to remove the

```
link_directories(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
```

statement from
    project/demo/CMakeLists.txt

I do not see why this should be necessary.
All the target you are linking to should be specified by
    target_link_libraries(...)